# JavaScript setting background image and transform effect in Raphael

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm learning SVG with using raphael (also new in programming), and I'm making a clock.

Let's take a look for clock first: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcJ2b.jpg)

As you can see the background image for the clock face is not in a nice position, so I want to reset its position on the clock face. I tried `rect-clip`, but it seems doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
  // new paper
  var paper = new Raphael(0,0,700,700);
  var background = paper.rect(0,0,1000,1000);
  background.attr({fill:"pink"});

  // clock face
  var face = paper.circle(350, 350, 250);
  var img = "url('deep.jpg')";
  face.attr({stroke:"black", "stroke-width":12,fill:img});
```

Another question is the transform effect, my English is not good but I will try to explain my question.

I'm using "`bounce`" effect for second hands ticking. Actually, it is working. However, it would not moves to the **360** degree to start rotating again, it only moves up to **359** degree then go back from **358** to **0** for start again.

In other words: the second hands only moves from **0 - 59** second then go back to **0** from **58** to start moving again, cannot move from **59 - 60** directly to start moving.

This is my transform code:

```
function startSeconds()
    {
      // seconds rotate degree calculation
      var now = new Date();
      // world clock part
      var localtime = now.getTime();
      var localOffset = now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
      var utc = localtime + localOffset;
      var target = utc + (3600000 * offset);
      var update = new Date(target);

      var sec =update.getSeconds();
      var sd = 6 * sec;

      seconds.animate({
        transform: [ 'r',sd,350,350]
      },500, "bounce");

      // play the clock ticking sound per second
      tick.play();

      secAnimate = setTimeout(function(){startSeconds()},500);
    }
```

If I delete the transform effect `bounce`, this issue will not happen.
So I don't know why is it exist, and want to keep it working in `bounce` effect without the issue that I mentioned if possible.

Hope someone can help me for these two questions.